# Cookies sent from browser not found in HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, cookies

Not all the cookies shown by Chrome Dev Tools as part of the Request Header are found in the HttpServletRequest object.

Here is a screenprint from Chrome Dev Tools, showing the request headers for the GET HTTP request.
You can see that the "cookie" includes the "_fbp" cookie:
[cookie request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDLM6.png)

From the Chrome Dev Tools application tab, you can see that the "_fbp" cookie is from my same Domain and has not expired and is for Path / so it should be included (which it was):
[cookie details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhFUQ.png)

We're running a Java Spring MVC backend and when the request comes to the controller endpoint, we have the "HttpServletRequest request" parameter.

Examining that "request" object, I find that it has some of the cookies which were observed as part of the request, but not all of them... and specifically not the "_fbp" cookie I'm looking for.

Tried examining the cookies in all the following manners:

1. Object rhc = request.getHeader("Cookie");
2. Cookie wuc = org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getCookie(request, "_fbp");
3. parameter @CookieValue(name="_fbp", required=false) String fbpCookie

but no matter how I inspect that request, the "_fbp" cookie is not there.  I noticed that most of the other cookies that are not found all have names beginning with underscores so I suspected maybe that is a naming convention that is ignored by Spring MVC but couldn't find any such rule.

Can anyone help explain the missing cookies?  How can I get that "_fbp" cookie value for server-side processing?  Appreciate any help.